# Blazor - Change Color of text based on condition

Tags: c#, html, css, blazor

I have this five ratings:

```
    if (model.CIIattainedrequired2021 > model.d4)
    {
        model.CIIrating2021 = "E";
    }
    if (model.CIIattainedrequired2021 < model.d4)
    {
        model.CIIrating2021 = "D";
    }
    if (model.CIIattainedrequired2021 < model.d3)
    {
        model.CIIrating2021 = "C";
    }
    if (model.CIIattainedrequired2021 < model.d2)
    {
        model.CIIrating2021 = "B";
    }
    if (model.CIIattainedrequired2021 < model.d1)
    {
        model.CIIrating2021 = "A";
    }
```

I display them in tables:

```
    <td class="text-center px-2 py-1 mx-0 text-xs">
    <p>@model.CIIrating2019</p>
</td><td class="text-center px-2 py-1 mx-0 text-xs">
    <p>@model.CIIrating2020</p>
</td><td class="text-center px-2 py-1 mx-0 text-xs">
    <p>@model.CIIrating2021</p>
</td><td class="text-center px-2 py-1 mx-0 text-xs">
    <p>@model.CIIrating2022</p>
</td><td class="text-center px-2 py-1 mx-0 text-xs">
    <p>@model.CIIrating2023</p>
</td><td class="text-center px-2 py-1 mx-0 text-xs">
    <p>@model.CIIrating2024</p>
</td><td class="text-center px-2 py-1 mx-0 text-xs">
    <p>@model.CIIrating2025</p>
</td><td class="text-center px-2 py-1 mx-0 text-xs">
    <p>@model.CIIrating2026</p>
```

And depending on the answer i would like to show the text in different colors as follow:

A-GREEN
B-LIGHTGREEN
C-YELLOW
D-ORANGE
E-RED

Comment: Your code example is weird, you have the same value in all your columns.

Comment: That was a mistake, i have edited,Thanks

Comment: @NikolasKypri Your model is probably not optimal (it would be more logical to have an object for each year). However, you could create a Dictionary<string, string> with the rating as key and the color as value.

Comment: I would recommend using a switch case instead of "if" condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First thing you will need will be to add a class using a variable
   in your td element.

```html
<td class="text-center px-2 py-1 mx-0 text-xs Add a class
        variable here like :@Color-code" >
```

2. Then in the code section of the page/component you need the variable you are using as the class above and a method that switches classes based on your logic:

```cs
@code{
    private string Color-code{get;set;}

     -//method that identifies the color

     private void setColorClassMethod(){

         if(condition){
             //Assuming you want to assign blue class in the case
             Color-Code="blueClass";
        }
    }
}
```

3. Finally in site.css file add colors to the classes you used above in variables like:

```css
.blueClass{
 //if you want to change background color
 background-color:blue;
 
 //if you want to change text color
 color:blue;
}
```

You can also achieve the same results via in line css. But I suggested classes because you might need to add further styling later to the td.

Comment: A dictionary would be easier and more clear. With your solution, you need to create one variable for each `CIIrating<year>`. The colors don't need to change depending on year but on rating which does not need to be dynamically assigned.

Answer (score 3):

For the text, add this:

```
<p style="color:@TextColor(model.CIIrating2020);">@model.CIIrating2020</p>
```

Then in your code add something like this to return the correct color based on the text:

```
private void TextColor(string text) {
switch(text) 
{
  case "A":
    return "#00FF00"
    break;
  case "B":
    return "#90EE90"
    break;
  //etc....
}
}
```